# How to reverse viewpager swiping

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, swipe-gesture

So my app is in RTL, and with that, the tabs are now ordered from right to left..!

..But when I swipe to slide between the tabs, it contradicts the common sense, so I want to reverse it..! see the picture to see the problem..!

What I want is..! > when I'm in Tab1 and then I swipe from left to right I want it to slide to Tab 2 and so on..!

is that possible..!?

[image]

***THE CODE***

---

**My Customer ViewPager**

```
public class CustomViewPager extends android.support.v4.view.ViewPager{
private boolean enabled;

public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.enabled = true;
}


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (this.enabled) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }

    return false;
}

public void setPagingEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
 }
 }
```

**My TabActivity (Helper Class)**

```
  public class TabbedActivity extends BaseActivity { 

 //I extend BaseActivity to avoid repeating UI code like toolbar and stuff..

protected CustomViewPager viewPager;
public OrdersAdapter adapter;
public TabLayout tabs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    tabs.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabs));


    tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            setTabSelected(tab);
        }


        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
  }


public void setTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

public void addTab(int title) {

    tabs.addTab(tabs.newTab().setText(getString(title)));

}

}
```

**My Activity that contains the Tablayout and has three fragments, one for each tab.**

```
public class MyOrders extends TabbedActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_orders);

    tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    addTab(R.string.NewOrderTabTitle); //tab1
    addTab(R.string.MyOrderTabTitle); // tab2
    addTab(R.string.FinOrderTabTitle); //tab3

     adapter = new OrdersAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabs.getTabCount());
    viewPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setPagingEnabled(true);

    tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


 }
}
```

---

**Update**

---

@regev avraham

> adding the tabs in the reverse order, and then use
>   `viewPager.setCurrentItem(adapter.getCount() - 1);` to select the last
>   tab.

based on your comment, here's what I did in the Activity that has tablayout

```
 //code...
 tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    addTab(R.string.FinOrderTabTitle); //tab3
    addTab(R.string.MyOrderTabTitle); // tab2
    addTab(R.string.NewOrderTabTitle); //tab1
 //code...

 viewPager.setCurrentItem(adapter.getCount() - 1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a little tricky, the android viewPager from right to left has a little bug, only the page titles are from right to left and the pages themselves don't.

In order to fix this, what I did was using the regular left to right layout and adding the tabs in the reverse order, and then use `viewPager.setCurrentItem(adapter.getCount() - 1);` to select the last tab.

This is how the result should look like:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0FzrLgjet7pSE9lMFFFT0JiekE

where size is the first tab, the display is the second and so on

To keep RTL behavior and the LTR behavior you should use this:

```
Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
if (config.getLayoutDirection() == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL)
{
     //use the RTL trick here
}
else
{
     //use the regular case here
}
```

Comment: I did this, but it only recorded my tabs position and didn't reversed the swipe.! can you show me what code to be changed exactly.!

Comment: Could you please add what you have done?, This solution worked for my app.

Comment: I update my answer with a video that shows the desired behavior. Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: YES.. that's exactly what I want, but I did what you said and it didn't work, so I'm more likely missing something, can you please check the classes above and see what should be changed and where exactly,, I really can use the help.!

Comment: Have you forgot to set the tab layout direction to be left to right instead of right to left?

Comment: It worked, but one last problem remains...! every time the activity that holds the 3 tabs gets launched it opens tab3 by default not 1..? how can I solve that..!?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

you can check this Lib

https://github.com/diego-gomez-olvera/RtlViewPager

and implement as below

```
dependencies {
...
compile 'com.booking:rtlviewpager:1.0.1'
}
```

> just add this instead of Viewpager

```
<com.booking.rtlviewpager.RtlViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: I can't do that, I don't wanna use library for this. I was hoping to find a solution without that..!

Comment: Thanks. Great library. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

I kind of faced this problem developing a **RTL** app. Here's what to do:

1. Add `tabs` in reverse order :

> tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab2");
>   tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab1");

2. Customize `ViewPager` Adapter to return `Fragments` in reverse order :

> ```
> public Fragment getItem(int position) {
>     switch (position) {
>         case 0:
>             Fragment2 f2 = new Fragment2();
>             return f2;
>         case 1:
>             Fragment1 f1 = new Fragment1();
>             return f1;
>         default:
>             return null;
>     }
> }
> ```

3. Select the last tab index at `OnCreate` :

> ```
> TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(1);
> tab.select();
> ```

4. Set direction of `TabLayout` to LTR :

> ```
> if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
>     tabLayout.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);
> }
> ```

5. And finally your `onTabSelected` event should looks like this :

> ```
> public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
>     viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
> }
> ```

It works well.

Answer (score 2):

If your `minSdkVersion` is 17+ you can do this to the tab layout:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

Comment: it didn't work, nothing changed when I added this line.!

Answer (score 1):

Now, You can do it in efficient way with a similar widget (support RTL paging-swipe).
It will automatically change the swipe direction according to the system local or you can set it manually.

Android has developed a new widget named `ViewPager2`

> `ViewPager2` is an improved version of the `ViewPager`,it offers
> enhanced functionality and addresses common difficulties with using
> `ViewPager`.

You can follow these simple steps to create `ViewPager2` integrated with `TabLayout`.

1. in `layout_main.xml` use this code:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
           android:id="@+id/toolbar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
           app:title="@string/app_name">
       </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

       <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
           android:id="@+id/tabs"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

   </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

   <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
       android:id="@+id/view_pager"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layoutDirection="locale"
       app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

   </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
   ```
2. Create adapter class with name `PagerAdapter`:

   ```
   public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
       public PagerAdapter(FragmentActivity fm) {
           super(fm);
       }

       @NonNull
       @Override
       public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
           switch (position) {
               case 0:
                   return YourFragment1.newInstance();
               case 1:
                   return YourFragment2.newInstance();
           }
           return null;
       }

       @Override
       public int getItemCount() {
           return 2;
       }
   }
   ```
3. In `MainActivity` (using view binding to get views from `xml` files):

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        //Tabs titles
        private static final int[] TAB_TITLES = new int[]{R.string.tab_text_1, R.string.tab_text_2};
        //Binding object
        private ActivityMainBinding binding;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //Inflate layout
            binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
            View view = binding.getRoot();
            setContentView(view);

            //Get TabLayout View
            TabLayout tabs = binding.tabs;
            //Get the viewPager View
            ViewPager2 viewPager = binding.viewPager;

            //Adapter for ViewPager
            PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(this);
            //Set Adapter for ViewPager
            viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

            //Integrate TabLayout with ViewPager
            //i use it to get tabs titles
            new TabLayoutMediator(tabs, viewPager, new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy() {
                @Override
                public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position) {
                    //set the title for the tab at position index
                    tab.setText(getResources().getString(TAB_TITLES[position]));
                }
            }).attach();
        }
   }
   ```

These resources I have used (you can read for more details):

- Create `ViewPager2` from start : [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view-2).
- Migrate from `ViewPager` to `ViewPager2` : [this link](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration).

I hope I helped with this.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is using this one line of code :

```
tabLayout.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);
```

for RTL ordering of your tabs, you should do it in pager :

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(adapter.getCount());
```

thanks to : [arash-hatemi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4905220/arash-hatami)

Answer (score 0):

You can set `ViewPager` `rotationY` to `180` degree and set `rotationY` of the child views on `instantiateItem` method to `180` degree.

Example:

```
ViewPager viewPager = new ViewPager(context);
viewPager.setRotationY(180F);
viewPagerMediaViewer.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View childView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.model_view_pager_item, container, false);

        container.addView(currentView);
        childView.setRotationY(180F);
        return currentView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).